# Import object from module of same name using __import__

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
root/
    __main__.py
    files/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
        baz.py
```

each file has an object in it with the same name as the file. You can imagine that the line `foo = MyObj(1)` is in foo.py and `bar = MyObj(2)` is in bar.py, etc.

In order to import the eponymous object from each file in `root/files/` I have the following code in `root/files/__init__.py`:

```
all_objects = []
#assume file_list is populated with list of files in root/files/
for file_name in file_list:
    mod_name = file_name[:-3]  #chop off the '.py'
    obj_name = file_name[:-3]  #remember, object I want has same name as module
    obj = __import__(mod_name, globals=globals(), locals=locals(), fromlist=(obj_name), level=1)
    all_objects.append(obj)
```

here, `obj` holds the modules foo, bar, ...etc and **not** the objects contained in those modules.

#### The Question:

How can I change my `__import__` invocation such that it will return the object contained in the module and not the module itself?

#### Workarounds:

I have found can do a `getattr(obj, obj_name)` to extract the object I want.

Comment: I don't think you can do that directly with `__import__`.  What is the problem with using `getattr`?

Comment: no problem, I just figured that I can do it with `from .mod import obj` so I should be able to do it using `__import__`

Comment: Not in one step.  The example in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) (towards the end of that section) shows that `from blah import blah` translates to multiple statements, one to import the module and another to grab individual values from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call something equivalent to :

```
obj = __import__("mymod", ...).mymod
```

to reproduce

```
from mymod import mymod
```

Getting the attribute of an object by its name can be done using

```
getattr(obj, 'mymod')
# or
obj.__dict__['mymod']
# or
vars(obj)['mymod']
```

Pick one. (I would go for `getattr` if I really had to).

```
obj = getattr(__import__(mod_name, globals=globals(), locals=locals(), fromlist=(obj_name), level=1), mod_name)
```

Comment: To generalize, you can make use of `operator.attrgetter` to retrieve multiple values: `a, b, c = attrgetter('a', 'b', 'c')(__import__("my mod", ...))`.